# While adding new column to table I get a new row instead

Tags: awk, sed, addition

I've tried many ways to add a new column to my table but it keeps adding a new line or row with the string instead of a new column when using this code that it wrote to add an R or F according to some values..

```
 awk -F'\t' '{if ($9 > $15) print $0,"F" ; else if ($9< $15) print $0,"R";}' file
```

or even a testing simple codes like these

```
awk '$0=$0" 1"' file
awk ' $NF=$NF" 1" ' file
```

At this stage I'm pretty sure that the file has something wrong, specially because it gave me some issues when I tried to sort based on the last column, which didnt work so I had to move it.. 
Anyways, have you seen this issue before? Is there a way to re-encode the table? Is just a big tab-delimited table so I'm not sure what's going on..

Comment: You probably created your file on Windows and so have spurious control-Ms at the end of each line. Run `cat -v` to see them and `dos2unix` or similar to remove them.

Comment: Thanks man. Yeah I see ^M at the end of the last column. I'll check that and try to convert it. Hopefully it will work

Comment: It will. Welcome to the ranks of the thousands before you who have experienced the same issue :-).

Comment: dos2unix didnt work for some reason but `sed -e "s/^M//"` worked perfectly (`sed -e 's/.$//'` removed the ^m but also the last character of the last column..) Anyhow, now I can work in peace hah. Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome and btw do not use any of the awk scripts you posted as they are the wrong way to do it. Your first one should be `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {print $0, ($9 > $15 ? "F" : "R")}' file` for example (assuming you didn't REALLY mean to not add anything at all when $9==$15).

Comment: Really? but it still works haha.. I was actually gonna add the $9==$15, but now I'm not sure haha

Comment: code that produces the output you want is the starting point for identifying how to do something, not the end point :-)